# Flexbox container too big when using wrap and 100% width item

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm trying to make a flexbox container for some items. 
There is one 100% width item inside as a headline.

The container is bigger ( width ) than needed.. why ?

Here is the code:

```css
.flex_container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex_head {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.flex_item {
  width: 175px;
  margin: 9px;
  border: 10px solid red;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex_container">
  <div class="flex_head">Flex Head</div>
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
<div>
```

[Demo on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2b9rz98/)

Comment: Because this is how the box model work. The parent container does not know when items wrap, so it will try to fit all the red in 1 row, hence fill its parent (the body) first. If you take out 2 red, or have a wide screen, you'll see it behave

Comment: @LGSon any idea how i could make the container always the width of the content, without any space left ?

Comment: If to be dynamic, use media query's, or a script to calculate it based on screen width

Comment: Here is a sample with media query's: https://jsfiddle.net/y2b9rz98/1/

Comment: @LGSon well the amout of items is variable too .. so i cannot calculate the width.

Comment: As long as the items width is known for all items, media query work, as you can see in my fiddle sample [https://jsfiddle.net/y2b9rz98/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/y2b9rz98/2/), and if not, you need a script ... and in my fiddle you might need to add a few more query's so it work on wider screens

Comment: @LGSon thanks a lot. I just found another solution. I add the flex: auto; value to the item. So they will expant to the aviable space of the container. Not the solution i wanted but its pretty easy

Comment: Yes, that is yet another way :)